# How to select a single element or layer in Photoshop CS6

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-photoshop, selection

I just moved to Photoshop CS6 at work, and I can't find how to select an element by clicking it. In CS5 I just <kbd>Alt</kbd>-clicked and it selected the element in the layers list.

Is this feature still available? If yes, how do I use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To select the layer that belongs to an element from the document window:

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> and right click
- OS X: Hold <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd> and right click

If you hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, it will select multiple layers. This works from almost all tools.

---

If *Auto-Select* is disabled, you can also drag to select multiple layers. First, <kbd>M</kbd> to select the move tool, then:

- Windows: Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and drag across the document
- OS X: Hold <kbd>⌘</kbd> and drag across the document

---

Finally, you can also always right-click inside the document to select a layer:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, just saw your reply, it's exactly what I was looking for, than you!

Answer (score 3):

With the *Move* tool selected, just click on the "Auto-Select" on top.

[image]